# refreshing a div panel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete a button on click from a layout itself . but unable to do it so far .
I am new to ajax and jQuery . 
I have a div on web page showing pending actions in the form of buttons now I want to remove 
each button when user clicks on it. this web page is auto refreshed in every 1 minute and all these pending actions are stored in a session variable .

now I am not getting a way to send this button id to another php script so that it can delete it from session array.

I tried following ..

```
     <script type='text/javascript'src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script> 
    function HideButton(butId)
      {
        $('#'+butId).hide();
        deleteButton(butId);

      }
    </script>


 <script>
 function deleteButton(id) {
     $.ajax({
      url: "delete_button.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" + id,
      success: function(response) {// Response handler}
   }); 
 }
 </script>

 <?php  // here is my php code ..

 //displaying button as follows in a loop 
 echo "<br><button type='button' id='".$id."' onclick=javascript:HideButton('".$id."') >".$pendingAction[$id]." </button>";
```

did not found any success yet.

Comment: You can do that with jquery `.remove()` function. See my answer and demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884043/refreshing-a-div-panel/24884249#24884249) for more detail

Comment: @ Hüseyin BABAL thanks for your response I edited my question by posting your given answer I am unable to find my error .

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery remove

DOM:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".hello" ).remove();
```

Output:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/Mqu34/)**

You can do that by following;

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Button 1"/>
    <input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="Button 2"/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
    var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).remove();
    // Uncomment below to activate ajax call
    //deleteButton(btnId);

})

function deleteButton(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "delete_button.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(response) {// Response handler}
    }); 
}
```

**PHP(delete_button.php):**

```
<?php

var btnId = $_POST["id"];
// delete from session by using $btnId
```

Comment: I think there is some problem with my design as I have my all code in sigle php file which runs and displays data using echo . now when I click my button to remove I can hide them but unable to run another php script to delete their ID . I echoed the script part too . To hide button on click I have a separate function  from yours you can check it in my question . any suggestions on this ?

Comment: You can just define another php file `delete_button.php` and put deletion code in this file.

Comment: but how to pass button id to this php script ?

Comment: via ajax. When you click button, you can send id. I think you need to use structure as in my answer

Comment: if I put the ajax code inside the HideButton function then it dont even hide the button . Is there any configuration need to be done for ajax in apache server ?

Comment: You have extra `</script>` tags. Check your spelling. And also check console if any error exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery remove action
`$('.removeButton').live(function () {
        $(this).remove();

   });`

Or you can also just hide the button when it is click

`$('.removeButton').live(function () {
        $(this).hide();

   });`

Comment: thanks for your response as these pending actions are re displayed on each refresh so I have stored them into a session array , if I simply hide them or delete them they will get displayed again in next refresh hence I have to delete them from session array variable too.